# How to execute sql before delete on commit on global temporary table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Context: An application is processing different files and inserting a lot of rows for each file via single inserts (can't be changed). It commits after each processed file (shouldn't be changed).

Task: "Doing something" with the sum of all the rows created by the processing of one file, wich means all the rows created from the last commit to the actual commit. This might be as simple as i.e  `insert into sum_table select sum(a), sum(b), id from gtt_work_table group by id` (Aggregating values for each processed file).

The first idea for an solution was quite simple: Creating a `global temporary table`with `on commit delete rows` and executing an `before delete`Trigger to do (nearly) whatever I like with the data for each transaction.

But it didn't work. As stated here [DELETE TRIGGER ON GTT](https://community.oracle.com/thread/97717) the trigger would only fire on explicit delete, not on the implicit delete caused by the commit. Though, the reference speaks of Oracle 8 so: **Is there a way to execute sql/plsql before an GTT is emptied nowadays?**

Using insert/for each row triggers works in general, but doesn't help me because of staying on single row level. Getting the application to do something before the commit (i.e. explicitly delete from the gtt) isn't possible, cause it is not customizable at that point.

Comment: if it doesn't know when the last row is, how does it know when to commit? Can the applicate code not be changed so that instead of committing, it calls the code to do the aggregating before it commits?

Comment: Editted above: It is not customizable at that point: I could do "something" at the start of the processing for all files and after that for each processed record, but i got no influence on "post process" nor is the last record identifiable through itself.

Comment: can the files be editted to have something that defines the final line (eg. `EOF`)? That way, you could have a trigger on the GTT before insert of each row to do the aggregation instead of inserting if the value is, eg, `EOF`?

Comment: Not really: The customizable logic is at that point allready abstracted from file properties, got just the data-records itself. Not even modifying the last record of each file at the very start of the whole process, i.e. by other tools is an option, because files might get splitted through the application itself before. Plus there are files from multiple sources.

Comment: alternatively, perhaps you could have a "normal" table, and have an id column in addition to the other columns, and then at the beginning of the file insert procedure, it selects a value from a new sequence that you'd create, and uses that to put a value into the id column for each row. Is that possible? That way, you'd have a way of grouping the data into blocks. The only trouble is knowing when to aggregate the final set of data, I guess.

Comment: The problem with that (or similar approaches) is: Right now everything is in a completely synchronized workflow: everything is done on the fly and in case of an error rolled back on the fly per file/transaction level as well. I don't really want to start seperate processes and cleanup and so on...using the gtt would be just perfect...if it would work ;)  Plus: Aggregating was just one example use case. Another would be syncing all records to a detail-table, but to save a little time not one by one as the application could do out of the box, but all from one transaction (kind of array-binding).

Comment: I think you're probably stuck with row-by-row processing in that case; at least, I don't know of anything clever that you could do.

Comment: Thank you anyway for your time!